# While loop - how to remove code duplication

Tags: c++, duplicates, code-duplication

It's not the first time I find myself in the following situation:

```
bool a = some_very_long_computation;
bool b = another_very_long_computation;
while (a && b) {
  ...
  a = some_very_long_computation;
  b = another_very_long_computation;
}
```

I don't want to compute everything in `while` condition, since computations are long and I want to give them appropriate names.
I don't want to create helper functions, because computation uses many local variables, and passing them all will make the code much less readable (and it will be some_huge_call).

It's unknown whether loop body will be executed at least once.

What is a good pattern in such situation? Currently I face it in C++, but I've encountered this in other languages as well. I can solve it by using additional variable `isFirstPass`, but it looks ugly (and, I guess, will cause some warnings):

```
bool a, b;
bool isFirstPass = true;
do {
  if (!isFirstPass) {
    ...
  } else {
    isFirstPass = false;
  }
  a = some_very_long_computation;
  b = another_very_long_computation;
} while (a && b);
```

Comment: I do believe helper functions are still the right way to do; but what about macros?

Comment: Macros - absolutely no. I don't want to pollute defines for some local stuff (and I can accidentally override some defines).

Comment: Meh, move it into its own method returning a bool.

Comment: Please update your first example making it clear how/if the first pass is different

Comment: @LyndonWhite, Sorry, I don't understand you. It's not different, it's the same pass as the others.

Comment: Why C++ tag? It's quite general problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct simplification of your code is:

```
while (
  some_very_long_computation &&
  another_very_long_computation
) {
  ...
}
```

If you want to keep the variables `a` and `b`:

```
bool a, b;
while (
  (a = some_very_long_computation) &&
  (b = another_very_long_computation)
) {
  ...
}
```

If you don't want to put the conditions into the `while` condition:

```
while (true) {
  bool a = some_very_long_computation;
  bool b = another_very_long_computation;
  if (!(a && b)) {
    break;
  }
  ...
}
```

You could also create helper lambdas (which have access to local variables):

```
auto fa = [&]() { return some_very_long_computation; };
auto fb = [&]() { return another_very_long_computation; };
while (fa() && fb()) {
  ...
}
```